Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\kamde\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\transformed\jetified-pspdfkit-2024.1.0-runtime.jar. pspdr

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.Could not resolve all files for configuration':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.Failed to transform pspdfkit-2024.1.0.aar (com.pspdfkit:pspdfkit:2024.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\kamde.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5bdb5f7eef7e9b20a7c8203d073ae2c1\transformed\jetified-pspdfkit-2024.1.0-runtime.jar.Error while dexing.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
